# How can I get elements out of an array with Template Toolkit?

Tags: perl, arrays, template-toolkit

I have an array of Paths which i want to read out with Template Toolkit.
How can I access the array Elements of this array?
The Situation is this:

```
my @dirs;
opendir(DIR,'./directory/') || die $!;
@dirs = readdir(DIR);
close DIR;
$vars->{'Tree'} = @dirs;
```

Then I call the Template Page like this:

```
$template->process('create.tmpl', $vars) 
   || die "Template process failed: ", $template->error(), "\n";
```

In this template I want to make an Tree of the directories in the array. How can I access them?

My idea was to start with a `foreach` in the template like this

```
[% FOREACH dir IN Tree.dirs %]
$dir
[% END %]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use references to pass arrays or hashes into your template:

```
$vars->{'Tree'} = \@dirs;
```

Then in the template:

```
[% FOR d = Tree %]
    [% d %]
[% END %]
```

Comment: Agreed. Always use references for arrays and hashes

Comment: Great this worked perfectly. Thank you! Will keep it in mind to always use references!